# Spark UI is completely distorted

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

Whenever I am launching my spark application Spark Master UI is completely distorted and I am not able to navigate to SQL/Storage and other tabs

Tried in multiple browser but everytime it's the same.
Please let me know for any property related to Spark UI or any setting which I need to do to see proper UI

Screenshot of Spark UI

[image]

Comment: What is ur Spark version ,old add all ur configuration

Comment: Sometimes it takes time for the UI to be loaded(In minutes ). You might consider staying on the tab for more time.

Comment: @vaquarkhan--Spark version is 2.4.3

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary--Job runs for 20 minutes but page doesn't populate by that time

Comment: did you try opening in another browser, it could simply be broken cache of the browser that makes css be misinterpreted

Comment: @milos--Yes I tried in all available browser Chrome firefox and IE..All have same result